# Globally Control thread pools in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

I have many I/O intensive jobs that are triggerred via Jersey webservice calls like this:

```
https://localhost/rest/execute/job/job1
```

I want to globally control the number of threads these jobs are using. How do I do this? I have thought of following two options, please suggest if I am in right direction or if there is a better solution.

**Approach 1:**

Create a wrapper class over `ThreadPoolExecutor` that provides threads to various services to submit runnables.

```
class GlobalThreadPool {

int corePoolSize    = 1;
int maximumPoolSize = 4;
BlockingQueue<Runnable> q =  BlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);

private ExecutorService pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, ..., q);

public Future<?> run (Runnable task) { pool.submit(task); }

}
```

Then use this class as `ServletContextListener` to start and shutdown with webservice.

- (+) REST resource gets an instance of this class from ServletContext and submits the requested job.
- (-)If a submitted task wants to use additional thread, it won't be able to do that as the `run()` method won't have access to service context.

**Approach 2:**

Create a *Singleton* of `GlobalThreadPool`. Then we Will **not** start it via web services listener. However, whenever a job needs it, it will instantiate the class and submit the runnable.

- (+) any job has access to the pool irrespective of whether it has access to ServletContext
- (-) shutting down the ExecutorService is not tied with webservice

Do you see any particular problem in any of these approaches that I might be missing? Is there any better (read standard) approach to do these things?

Comment: Why do you need a new class at all?  How does `ThreadPoolExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize(n)` not meet your needs?

Comment: well, I think I wanted to create a single wrapper class so that various jobs can all get their jobs submitted to a central place. How otherwise will I share the same `ThreadPoolExecutor` to all the jobs run by the webservice?

Comment: And how would you share the same wrapper class instance?  However you would share _that_, you could share a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the same way.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my line of thought was in order to share the same `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance to all the arbitrarily requested jobs, I would need a *Singleton* or I would have to share the instance via some other means, e.g. `ServletContext`

Comment: Hmm, I don't know Jersey, so perhaps I do not understand your problem.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. I am not saying anything about `Jersey`. You can make this wrapper `class` `singleton` (Where you will maintain a single tread pool and a single `ExecutorService`) and get the `singleton` object where ever you want to have and submit the `Runnable`s from there. Look at a way to get the singleton object of this to where ever you want to call `run()`, I know Spring can do it pretty easily using dependency injection.